# Unable to cast a COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, com

I'm having a problem with a vb.net application that generates a Word document. In short my program makes a copy of an existing Word file, removes certain blocks of text and then saves the file.

This works on multiple computers with different versions of Windows and Office. However on a few computers we get the following COM error:
`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast a COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'.`

I've already repaired the Office installation and have made sure the programmability components are checked when installing, but the error remains.

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: I just used google with you message and I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d34c4f78-46f3-478e-9c44-95ea8461e46f/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-office-interop-word?forum=vsto). Look at the answer there. Did you checked this? Beside this, I found much more links that talk about the same issue...

Comment: And may be this [link is the most important](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dau-blog/2012/04/20/how-to-solve-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationclass-to-interface-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-_application/) and the answer.

Comment: @xMRi, I followed the instructions on both pages and did find multiple keys as described. However, deleting them doesn't help. Any other ideas?